# How to see JBOSS has started/stopped from commandline

Tags: linux, jboss

Is there some linux/jboss command I can use in a script to see if jboss started. 
I have to start up a couple in a specified order and one of the jbosses must
be started before the others can be started up.

/T

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/StartupAndDeploymentCheck) ,With the following command you can try to read the server "Started" attribute

```
twiddle get "jboss.system:type=Server" Started
Started=true
```

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 19, you can install the jboss-as package, which comes with a nice startup script, and you can check the status just like any other daemon: systemctl status jboss-as

Similarly for Fedora 20 and Wildfly: systemctl status wildfly .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash

CHECK_TIMEOUT=$1;
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Checking if JBoss is running with timeout of $1 s.";
else
    echo "Checking if JBoss is running with default timeout of 60 s.";
    CHECK_TIMEOUT=60;
fi

while [[ $CHECK_TIMEOUT -ne 0 ]]
do
    sleep 1;
    JBOSS_STATE=`~/jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh 'connect,:read-attribute(name=server-state),q' | grep result`;
    if [[ -z $JBOSS_STATE ]]; then
        JBOSS_STATE="stopped";
    else
        JBOSS_STATE=`echo "$JBOSS_STATE" | tr -s \" " " | cut -d ' ' -f 4`;
    fi
    echo "JBoss is $JBOSS_STATE";
    if [[ $JBOSS_STATE == "running" ]]; then
        exit 0;
    fi
    ((CHECK_TIMEOUT-=1));
done
exit 1;
```